# ArrayList em C# não mostra valores digitados pelo usuário

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos

Fiz um **ArrayList em C# que mostra apenas o nome, idade e curso de um estudante** . Mas o **erro CS0029 diz que não é possível converter implicitamente string paraint na linha 27 e 37,** antes de eu inserir a variável idade tinha executado, mas não mostrava nada.

```
using System.Collections;
using static System.Console;

public class Estudante
{
    public string Nome;
    public int idade;
    public string Curso;

    public string Imprimir()
    {
        return "Nome: " + Nome + " Idade: " + idade + " Curso: " + Curso;
    }
}

public class ArrayEstudante
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        ArrayList Vetor = new ArrayList();
        Estudante estudante1 = new Estudante();

        Vetor.Add(estudante1);
        Write("Digite o nome do estudante: ");
        ((Estudante)Vetor[0]).Nome = ReadLine();
        Write("Digite a idade do estudante: ");
        ((Estudante)Vetor[0]).idade = ReadLine();
        Write("Digite o nome do curso: ");
        ((Estudante)Vetor[0]).Curso = ReadLine();

        WriteLine();

        Vetor.Add(estudante1);
        Write("Digite o nome do estudante: ");
        ((Estudante)Vetor[1]).Nome = ReadLine();
        Write("Digite a idade do estudante: ");
        ((Estudante)Vetor[1]).idade = ReadLine();
        Write("Digite o nome do curso: ");
        ((Estudante)Vetor[1]).Curso = ReadLine();

        ReadKey();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Há algum motivo para usar ArrayList e não usar IList genérica?

Comment: O assunto que estou vendo é ArrayList em POO nas aulas, IList eu nunca vi.

Comment: a entrada do ReadLine é sempre do tipo string, como seu idade é int aponta isso, o que você poderia era forçar um cast no readline para int ou chamar o parser, mas isso não necessariamente assegura que será digitado um numero

Answer (score 1):

O `ArrayList` é uma classe usada anterior a chegada dos genéricos em C#. Na própria documentação da Microsoft sobre o `ArrayList` pode-se encontrar:

> Não recomendamos que você use a classe ArrayList para o novo desenvolvimento. Em vez disso, recomendamos que você use a classe List genérica

Fonte: [Arraylist Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netframework-4.8)

Recomendo que já comece a aprender de um jeito mais "certo".
Você pode ler sobre [IList](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8).

Como Lucas Miranda falou nos comentários, a função `Console.ReadLine()` tem um retorno do tipo `string` e esta conversão implícita não pode ser feita. O certo é você converter o resultado para inteiro e depois atribuí-lo a sua variável. E o mais certo seria validar o input do usuário.

Seguindo a sua lógica de raciocínio, usando `List<T>` teria um seguinte código:

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    // Criamos uma lista de estudantes
    List<Estudante> estudantes = new List<Estudante>();

    // criamos um novo estudante
    Estudante estudante1 = new Estudante();

    // solicitamos seus dados
    Console.Write("Digite o nome do estudante: ");
    estudante1.Nome = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Digite a idade do estudante: ");
    estudante1.idade = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("Digite o nome do curso: ");
    estudante1.Curso = Console.ReadLine();

    // terminamos de solicitar os dados, podemos adicionar na lista de estudantes
    estudantes.Add(estudante1);

    // cria o segundo estudante
    Estudante estudante2 = new Estudante();

    Console.Write("Digite o nome do estudante: ");
    estudante2.Nome = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Digite a idade do estudante: ");
    estudante2.idade = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("Digite o nome do curso: ");
    estudante2.Curso = Console.ReadLine();

    estudantes.Add(estudante2);
}
```

Perceba que não fazemos casting (converso explícita) em nenhum momento porque ele já sabe que dentro dessa lista há um objeto do tipo `Estudante`. No caso do ArrayList, você pode guardar qualquer coisa lá, inclusive, coisas que não são do tipo `Estudante`.

Perceba que usei `Convert.ToInt32` para converter uma string para `inteiro` evitando assim o erro que você teve.
Lembrando que sempre deve validar o que o usuário digita.

Comment: A resposta não é de toda ruim, mas você não sabe o esforço que estou tendo para convencer ele converter string em número do jeito correto, agora vem você fala para ele fazer do jeito errado,,,

Comment: Entendo! Realmente, usar um int.TryParse seria muito melhor ou alguma coisa semelhante. Quando tiver um tempo, farei a edição.

Comment: Eu utilizei `if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out estudante1.idade)) return 1;` e `if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out estudante2.idade)) return 1;` agora o problema é o seguinte **Erro CS0246: O nome do tipo ou do namespace "List<>" não pode ser encontrado (está faltando uma diretiva using ou uma referência de assembly?)**

Comment: @CarlosA. Faltou importar o pacote: System.Collections.Generic é só adicionar ele no topo do código utilizando using

Comment: @KevinKouketsu na linha 21 ou seja `List<Estudante> estudantes = new List<Estudante>();` que você fez

Comment: @KevinKouketsu uso `estudante1.Imprimir()` e `estudante2.Imprimir()` ou `estudante.Imprimir()`?

Comment: usei `estudante1.Imprimir()` e `estudante2.Imprimir()` executa mais não retorna o que foi digitado.